# ELIFECYCLE error - firebase functions deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy firebase functions.

I know there are plenty of posts about this issue but none of the solutions fixed my issue

any idea how to fix it?

```
i  deploying firestore, functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/Nat-Serrano/Desktop/Reny/functions
> eslint .


/Users/Nat-Serrano/Desktop/Reny/functions/index.js
  18:65  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Nat-Serrano/.npm/_logs/2021-12-10T06_23_26_783Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

this is my eslint

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the error get resolved after changing the package.json as mentioned in your answer?

Comment: yes. at least the deploy

Answer (score 2):

nevermind, I changed my package.json

before:

```
"lint": "eslint .",
```

after:

```
"lint": "eslint",
```